# Forked a PHP tinyboard site and unable to post in Chinese (but able to do it through admin panel)

Tags: php, mysql, apache

so i forked a site from the project [OpenIB](https://github.com/OpenIB/OpenIB)
and the problem is that when i try to post in chinese or any emojis, it wouldnt show up. my test page is [test](http://shitchan.com/test)

the interesting part about it is that when i try to access via mod.php, and try to view or post, chinese/emojis are able to be shown up.
ive checked html pages, they have utf8 set up, and my sql has default utf8 setting as well.
i wonder if its a permission problem or something, and ive provided the github source code page

1. when i try to post threads as anonymous, only post.php method is used
2. when i try to post as admin, mod.php and /inc/mod/pages.php is used. 
   i think it has something to do with pages.php, it might has given somme certain permission that i can use to post chinese/emojis
3. checked my mysql setting using `show variables like '%character%'`
   all of them are utf8 except that the character_set_filesystem is binary. i think its not a problem

Comment: Are you sure you have UTF-8 *all the way through*? See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through) for general advice.

Comment: ive tried it, but the problem is that when i use the mod mode they all show up perfectly, is it possible that something rejected anonymous users to submit utf8 to the server? im pretty noob on mysql and php

Comment: Try with Latin characters first, then test other things. é, then Ω, then ♻︎, 字 and then  and see which work and which don't.

Comment: when i try to post  é, Ω and 字, it returns back "body too short or empty", and when i try with  ♻︎ and  it returns "Caught fatal error: Call to undefined function apc_fetch() in /var/www/OpenIB/inc/cache.php on line 49"

Comment: Not sure what's causing those errors since the corresponding insert code isn't shown. Can you reproduce this independently of the PHP forum software? This could be a bug in the software, or that the software has to be set up in a very specific way.